# Where to write the save function in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Where should I write my `save()` function in Django: in `models.py` in a model class, or in `forms.py` in a form?

For example :
models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def save():
      ........ some code to override it.......
```

forms.py

```
class  Addcustomer(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Customer
       fields = ('name',)
   def save():
     ........code to override it....
```

Where should I override my save function?

Comment: please can everyone give me a use case in which, where i shall override save in model.py or form.py , according to @Sardorbek Imomaliev, i get to know the use case and benefit of over riding save in forms.py !

Comment: @Moderator Why this question got downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Default realization of `ModelForm`'s save calls `Model`'s save. But it is usually better to override it on `form` because it also runs validation. So if you are already using form I would suggest overriding `ModelForm.save`. And by overriding I mean extending using `super`

Here is default realization of `ModelForm.save`

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    """
    Save this form's self.instance object if commit=True. Otherwise, add
    a save_m2m() method to the form which can be called after the instance
    is saved manually at a later time. Return the model instance.
    """
    if self.errors: # there validation is done
        raise ValueError(
            "The %s could not be %s because the data didn't validate." % (
                self.instance._meta.object_name,
                'created' if self.instance._state.adding else 'changed',
            )
        )
    if commit:
        # If committing, save the instance and the m2m data immediately.
        self.instance.save()
        self._save_m2m()
    else:
        # If not committing, add a method to the form to allow deferred
        # saving of m2m data.
        self.save_m2m = self._save_m2m
    return self.instance

save.alters_data = True
```

Comment: thanks is helpful , first from the perspective of validation, because i need to validate. but can you give me a single use case where i shall override save function in model.py

Comment: @dilwaria there is almost never actual need to override model's save. Because it does many things that shouldn't be touched/changed. Usually if you want to add steps on model's save you can use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/). In my experience people override model's save only because they don't know about signals or know exactly what they are doing.

Comment: @Sardorbrek  thanks for the insight and the best practice thing! i will also go through the django signals !